# How can image format be determined from a byte stream?

Tags: python, opencv, udp, python-imaging-library

I am trying to write a python script which joins a webcam multicast and stores each frame received as an image on the local hard drive.  Typically, one may click on the link to the stream and the stream is played back in the browser, or in VLC media player.

The stream is supplied as a UDP multicast, to which I can subscribe with the following code (Python33, Windows 7):

```
import socket
import struct

MCAST_GRP = '(the ip)'
MCAST_PORT = (the port)

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(('', MCAST_PORT))
mreq = struct.pack("4sl", socket.inet_aton(MCAST_GRP), socket.INADDR_ANY)

sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)


while True:
    data = sock.recv(1316)

    print(data)
```

This is where I am stuck. data appears to be a byte stream in which I am hoping an image is encoded, but without knowing for sure which format the picture is in, I am having trouble proceeding to decode this stream and turn it into an actual image. Printing data shows output that is of this sort:

b'G\x01\x00\x1c\xc4 ...' 
b'G\x01\x00\x18\x87 ...'
b'GA\x015p\x00\xff\xff ...'

How can I convert these byte streams to an actual image? Are there markers associated with jpg / png formats that I need to look for and isolate?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: You can take a look at this library: http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/

Comment: Tried using ImageFile.Parser().feed(data), but I get an error: IOError('cannot parse this image'). Maybe I have to decode first, or isolate where the actual image is in the stream?

Comment: Also, I used VLC to figure out that it uses the H264 - MPEG-4 AVC codec to decode this stream.

Answer (score 0):

If in the stream is also the header of the file (image), it contains the info about the format, for example see [wiki for BMP file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format)

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on python, but a bit of an expert on video streaming, and I suspect you might think of it in a wrong way from the very beginning. When you join multicast and receive the stream, it has little to do with static pictures. Video would normally be encoded according to H.264 standard, and frames are structured in so called group of pictures (GOP). GOP consists of I, P, and B frames, for example IPBBPBBPBBPBBPI, of which static pictures are I frames only. Normally, one would store I frames as sized down images to display them during FF or RW operations. To extract I frames from video stream you would normally use stand alone library, and the most usable I know - https://www.ffmpeg.org/

It will allow you decode the stream down to all 24,25, or whatever it is number of frames every second, in case you really want to store *every* picture in the video...

Comment: Thanks for the fantastic response, and correctly identifying my lack of understanding. 

I am now using OpenCV (called from python) to decode the stream. To my understanding --I could be wrong-- opencv uses ffmpeg to decode the stream. Do you know if ffmpeg is good at decoding MPEG-4 Part 10 AVC format? VLC opens and shows the stream without any problems, but my opencv solution shows fragmented images (almost like the some information doesn't arrive and the same pixels are repeated to finish the image).

Comment: well, H.264 and AVC are basically synonyms:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC - so ffmpeg handles that. Whether you use ffmpeg or anything else, you need to decode (or decompress) the video in order to get I frames only (actual pictures). Maybe have a look here to check how it works http://pr0gr4mm3r.com/linux/convert-video-to-images-and-back-using-ffmpeg/